# How to add Spatie Role Condition in Login using Laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-passport, laravel-permission

I am using Laravel-8, laravel-passport and spatie-permission for restful api. Already, I have this code in the Controller.

I have this controller for the Admin:

```
public function adminLogin(Request $request)
{
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken;
        $success['name'] =  $user->name;

        return $this->sendResponse($success, 'User login successfully.');
    }
    else{
        return $this->sendError('Unauthorised.', ['error'=>'Unauthorised']);
    }
}
```

I want only 'Super Admin' to be able to use the Admin Controller to Login. If not 'Super Admin', it should indicate unathorized.

How do I include the code below to what I already have above or any other best way?

```
    if($user->hasRole('Super Admin'))
        $res = User::with(['roles', 'employee', 'company'])->find($user->id);
    else
        $res = User::with('roles')->find($user->id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the user's role after attempting authentication.

```php
public function adminLogin(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if (!$user->hasRole('Super Admin') {
            Auth::logout();

            return $this->sendError('Unauthorised.', ['error'=>'Unauthorised']);
        }

        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken;
        $success['name'] =  $user->name;

        return $this->sendResponse($success, 'User login successfully.');
    }

    return $this->sendError('Unauthorised.', ['error'=>'Unauthorised']);
}
```

Comment: You would want to call `Auth::logout()` if the check for a `Super Admin` role fails.

Comment: Edited the answer.